# Amazone Lex: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am new to Lex Platform as well as nodejs and currently using V2 console. Here the task is to create a bot using Lex that will call ServiceNow API and will create and incident by taking details like short description and type of ticket.

The problem is fulfillment done by Lambda function and code used here is Nodejs in which I am not well versed and the person who was working in this has left.
I tried to go through multiple documents and I am not getting any leads.
Then I followed the below link how to log a ticket in servicenow using Lex
https://chatbotslife.com/a-chatbot-for-servicenow-using-amazon-connect-lex-and-lambda-cb7ed7f090b4

However I am stuck with the error.

This is how the code looks like
[fulfillment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnoy3.png)

[fulfillment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08oPK.png)
[fulfillment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbTF.png)

This is how in console it looks like where it is correctly identifying the intent but then it fails when slot type is included:

[lex console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzDla.png)

When I checked coludwatch logs this is the event response:

```
2021-08-19T11:29:21.061Z    7c5a3471-ed64-496a-83ba-fb7dc8d2f233    INFO    Received event: {
    "sessionId": "21213557437979",
    "inputTranscript": "raise an incident",
    "interpretations": [
        {
            "intent": {
                "slots": {
                    "shortDesc": {
                        "shape": "Scalar",
                        "value": {
                            "originalValue": "raise an incident",
                            "resolvedValues": [
                                "raise an incident"
                            ],
                            "interpretedValue": "raise an incident"
                        }
                    },
                    "ticketType": {
                        "shape": "Scalar",
                        "value": {
                            "originalValue": "incident",
                            "resolvedValues": [
                                "incident"
                            ],
                            "interpretedValue": "incident"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "confirmationState": "None",
                "name": "LogTicket",
                "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
            },
            "nluConfidence": 1
        },
        {
            "intent": {
                "slots": {},
                "confirmationState": "None",
                "name": "FallbackIntent",
                "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
            }
        }
    ],
    "responseContentType": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
    "messageVersion": "1.0",
    "sessionState": {
        "intent": {
            "slots": {
                "shortDesc": {
                    "shape": "Scalar",
                    "value": {
                        "originalValue": "raise an incident",
                        "resolvedValues": [
                            "raise an incident"
                        ],
                        "interpretedValue": "raise an incident"
                    }
                },
                "ticketType": {
                    "shape": "Scalar",
                    "value": {
                        "originalValue": "incident",
                        "resolvedValues": [
                            "incident"
                        ],
                        "interpretedValue": "incident"
                    }
                }
            },
            "confirmationState": "None",
            "name": "LogTicket",
            "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
        },
        "originatingRequestId": "a2857e61-32c3-4018-8904-927f3342cf41"
    },
    "bot": {
        "aliasId": "TSTALIASID",
        "aliasName": "TestBotAlias",
        "name": "TFS-connect-now",
        "version": "DRAFT",
        "localeId": "en_US",
        "id": "VTHO1CRSJN"
    },
    "inputMode": "Text"
}
```

And after this it is throwing an error

```
2021-08-19T11:29:21.062Z    7c5a3471-ed64-496a-83ba-fb7dc8d2f233    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:7:38)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

In chrome network console it shows 424 error.

Any leads how this can be solved ?

Comment: Was this working properly at the time the person left was in charge?

Comment: No this was not implemented

Comment: It seem the data from lex and the data that lambda expect are different. So modifying whichever will work.

Comment: @shimo I figured out that I am supposed to use v2 response format and I did appropriate modifications yet the error remains same.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the format of the event. The name of the intention is as follows:

event.sessionState.intent.name

var intent = event.sessionState.intent.name